# Mapping CHAR(0) in MySQL to boolean in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table named `refund_rule` in mysql*(version 5.5)*. Here is it's definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `refund_rule` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PERCENTAGE` char(0) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'BOOLEAN shortcut.NULL<=>false,EMPTY<=>true',
  `DEDUCTION_AMOUNT` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

The corresponding class in Hibernate*(version 3.2)* is named `RefundRule`. The HBM file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernatesample.dao.RefundRule" table="refund_rule" catalog="back_end_proc">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="percentage" type="string">
            <column name="PERCENTAGE" length="0">
                <comment>BOOLEAN shortcut.NULL&lt;=&gt;false,EMPTY&lt;=&gt;true</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
        <property name="deductionAmount" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="DEDUCTION_AMOUNT" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The class generated by the wizard in NetBeans*(version 7.0)* was this:

```
public class RefundRule  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer id;
     private String percentage;
     private Integer deductionAmount;

    public CancellationRule() {
    }

    public CancellationRule(String percentage, Integer deductionAmount) {
       this.percentage = percentage;
       this.deductionAmount = deductionAmount;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPercentage() {
        return this.percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    public Integer getDeductionAmount() {
        return this.deductionAmount;
    }

    public void setDeductionAmount(Integer deductionAmount) {
        this.deductionAmount = deductionAmount;
    }

}
```

I added 2 more methods in it `setPercentage(boolean)` & `isPercentage()`, and changed the method `setPercentage(String)` , so that i can use that `String` object as `boolean` in my Java*(version 1.6)* program.

```
public class RefundRule  implements java.io.Serializable {

    .
    .
    .

    public String getPercentage() {
        return this.percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage==null?null:"";
    }

    .
    .
    .

    public void setPercentage(boolean percentage){
        setPercentage(percentage?"":null);
    }

    public boolean isPercentage(){
        return percentage!=null;
    }

}
```

My Question is:

Is there any way that I can keep only two methods: `setPercentage(boolean)` and `isPercentage()` , and map the `boolean percentage` variable to `PERCENTAGE CHAR(0)` variable in mysql.

===================================================================

**EDIT**  added on  *2013-11-23*

Following the answer by @GreyBeardedGeek , I made following changes in code:

(Changes in brief)

1. Added Class CharToBoolUserType
2. Changed the `type`-attribute of hbm-element: *percentage* in RefundRule.hbm.xml

(Code related to above mentioned changes)

1. The class CharToBoolUserType:

   ```
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Types;

   import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
   import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

   public class CharToBoolUserType implements UserType {

       private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.CHAR};

       @Override
       public Object assemble(Serializable serializable, Object object) throws HibernateException {
           return serializable;
       }

       @Override
       public Object deepCopy(Object object) throws HibernateException {
           return object;
       }

       @Override
       public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
           return (Serializable) value;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
          if (x == y) {
              return true;
          } else if (x == null || y == null) {
              return false;
          } else {
              return x.equals(y);
          }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isMutable() {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
           return resultSet.getObject(names[0]) != null;
       }

       @Override
       public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
           preparedStatement.setObject(index, ((Boolean) value).booleanValue() ? "" : null);
       }

       @Override
       public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
           return original;
       }

       @Override
       public Class returnedClass() {
           return boolean.class;
       }

       @Override
       public int[] sqlTypes() {
           return SQL_TYPES;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode(Object object) throws HibernateException {
           if (object == null) {
               return 0;
           }
           // is `object` a String ? Or boolean?
           return 1;
       }
   }
   ```
2. The file RefundRule.hbm.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
   <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="hibernatesample.dao.RefundRule" table="refund_rule" catalog="back_end_proc">
           <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
               <column name="ID" />
               <generator class="identity" />
           </id>
           <property name="percentage" type="hibernatesample.dao.CharToBoolUserType">
               <column name="PERCENTAGE" length="0">
                   <comment>BOOLEAN shortcut.NULL&lt;=&gt;false,EMPTY&lt;=&gt;true</comment>
               </column>
           </property>
           <property name="deductionAmount" type="java.lang.Integer">
               <column name="DEDUCTION_AMOUNT" />
           </property>
       </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
   ```

Since I want the code of the `class CharToBoolUserType` to be complete in all sense, I have following questions:
1.    What is the class of `object` in `hashCode(Object object)`, `Boolean` or `String`? Who calls this method?
2.    What the method `public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)` supposed to do? replace `original` with `target` and set/put it in `owner`. In this case: is `original` of `String` type, `target` of `Boolean` type, and `owner` of `RefundRule` type ?

Any suggestion(s) to improve this code is welcome.

=================================================

Just for reference, the class RefundRule is like this now:

```
public class RefundRule  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer id;
     private boolean percentage;
     private Integer deductionAmount;

    public RefundRule() {
    }


    public RefundRule(boolean percentage, Integer deductionAmount) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.deductionAmount = deductionAmount;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getDeductionAmount() {
        return this.deductionAmount;
    }

    public void setDeductionAmount(Integer deductionAmount) {
        this.deductionAmount = deductionAmount;
    }

    public void setPercentage(boolean percentage){
        this.percentage=percentage;
    }

    public boolean isPercentage(){
        return percentage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for Hibernate's UserType, which allows you to provide a custom type mapping.

See, for example, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom